# Makefile dynamic rules based on a file

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I have a number of binary files (images, etc.). I need to copy some of them to an output directory as part of my build process.

The list of files that need to be copied is based on some rather complex logic, and it are generated dynamically by a Python script.

Suppose I have the following in `deps.txt`:

```
a.png
b.gif
c.mp4
```

How could I use a makefile to copy any necessary files to the output directory?

For example, if the output directoryalready included `c.mp4` and an out-of-date version of `b.gif`, running the makefile would copy `a.png` and `b.gif` to the output directory (but not `c.mp4`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way, if you're using GNU make, is to use an auto-generated include file, like this:

```
deps.txt.mk: deps.txt
        cat $< | while read f; do echo "\$$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$$f: $$f ; cp $$< $$@"; done > $@

-include deps.txt.mk
```

If you're not using GNU make, you'll have to use recursion instead: have a rule that creates the makefile (like above), then run `$(MAKE) -f deps.txt.mk` to actually do the installation.  Let me know if you need that example.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to take a wild guess that you also wrote http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html. A recommended read.

Comment: +1! I may suggest to use `while ... done < $<` instead of `cat $< | while ... done`. `Cat` is an external utility and it is not essential here.